# Cant access classes through Object Java RPG character builder

Tags: java, oop, object, inheritance

Im trying to create a small character builder, using inheritance. i have CreateCharacter CharacterRace then a Dwarf class. i made a variable with type CharacterRace in CreateCharacter and a variable with type Dwarf in CharacterRace. i have an object of CreateCharacter in my main method demo and its not letting me call the methods from the Dwarf class, to make a dwarf character. im thinking ineed to pass a dwarf object in characterRace? im just not sure how. heres my code: (its a bit long my apologies)

```
   package characterCreation;

public class CreateCharacter {
    private CharacterClass characterClass;
    private CharacterRace characterRace;
    private Name name;
    public CreateCharacter(String characterName,CharacterClass characterClass,CharacterRace characterRace) {
        this.name = new Name(characterName);
        this.characterClass = characterClass;
        this.characterRace = characterRace;
    }
    public CreateCharacter(){

    }
    public CharacterClass getCharacterClass() {
        return characterClass;
    }
    public void setCharacterClass(CharacterClass characterClass) {
        this.characterClass = characterClass;
    }
    public CharacterRace getCharacterRace() {
        return characterRace;
    }
    public void setCharacterRace(CharacterRace characterRace) {
        this.characterRace = characterRace;
    }
    public Name getName(){
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(Name name){
        this.name = name;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "CreateCharacter [name=" + name + ", characterRace=" + characterRace + ", characterClass="
                + characterClass + "]";
    }



}


    package characterCreation;

    public class CharacterRace {
        protected String raceName;
        protected double mana;
        protected double hp;
        private Dwarf dwarf;
        public CharacterRace(String raceName,double mana, double hp) {
            this.raceName = raceName;
            this.mana = mana;
            this.hp = hp;
        }   
        public CharacterRace(){

        }
        public String getRaceName() {
            return raceName;
        }

        public Dwarf getDwarf() {
            return dwarf;
        }

        public void setDwarf(Dwarf dwarf) {
            this.dwarf = dwarf;
        }
        public double getMana() {
            return mana;
        }

        public double getHp() {
            return hp;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "CharacterRace [dwarf=" + dwarf + "]";
        }

        }

    package characterCreation;

public class Dwarf extends CharacterRace {



    public Dwarf(String raceName,double mana, double hp) {
        super(raceName,mana,hp);

    }

    public double getMana() {
        mana = 5;
        return mana;
    }

    public double getHp() {
        hp = 10;
        return hp;
    }


    public String getRaceName(){
        return raceName = "Dwarf";
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Dwarf [mana=" + mana + ", hp=" + hp + ", getRaceName()=" + getRaceName() + "]";
    }
}
package characterCreation;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class CharacterDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        CreateCharacter create = new CreateCharacter();
        System.out.println("Choose your Race: ");
        String userRace = input.next();

        create.setName(new Name("Daxel"));
        //create.setCharacterRace(race);
        System.out.println(create.getName());
        //Dwarf dwarf = new Dwarf();
        System.out.println(create.getCharacterRace().getDwarf().getRaceName());
        //System.out.println(create.getCharacterRace().setDwarf(new Dwarf("dwarf",10,5)));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to call setCharacterRace() on create; then call setDwarf() on the characterRace; otherwise create.getCharacterRace() would be null and create.getCharacterRace().getDwarf() would throw NullPointerException.

I don't understand the logic behind your code, but try the code below:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        CreateCharacter create = new CreateCharacter();
        System.out.println("Choose your Race: ");
        String userRace = input.next();

        create.setName(new Name("Daxel"));

        //***********new code starts******
        CharacterRace myRace = new CharacterRace(userRace, 20, 9);
        myRace.setDwarf(new Dwarf("dwarf",10,5));
        create.setCharacterRace(myRace);
        //***********new code ends********

        //create.setCharacterRace(race);
        System.out.println(create.getName());
        //Dwarf dwarf = new Dwarf();
        System.out.println(create.getCharacterRace().getDwarf().getRaceName());
        //System.out.println(create.getCharacterRace().setDwarf(new Dwarf("dwarf",10,5)));
    }
```

Comment: thank you very much, At this time i was just trying to figure out how to call the different methods from all the different classes to make the object, i was going to implement user input to call based off of what they input afterwards. Would there be a better way to design this, or am i on the right track

Comment: See my updated code which I use user input "userRace" to construct CharacterRace object. Again, it totally depends on how you design your game/character/race. Like, why would you put Dwarf as a property of CharacterRace while Dwarf itself extends CharacterRace?